# Python 3.4 Check Text Value of Hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I am making a login program in python. One of its functions is creating an account of which the username and hashed password are stored in a text file. It was working fine, but I wanted to add password confirmation to it, so I added another password input and hashed it. When making an account 'guest', however, when I compare the hashes with a while loop like so:

```
while encryptedpass != encryptedpass2:
    confirmedpass = getpass.getpass(prompt = 'The passwords did not match. Please try again.')
    encryptedpass2 = hashlib.sha512(confpass.encode('ascii'))
```

it (the while loop) always runs. The reason is because the values of the variables, without entering a password and just pressing enter, are `<sha512 HASH object @ 0x7f8276c09da0>` and `<sha512 HASH object @ 0x7f8276c09cb0>`. They are both different. I would like to be able to check the actual text value of these hashes, but I do not know how to. Could someone please tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that adding .hexdigest() is the function you are looking for.